# Manipulating Select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that contains multiple rows.

Each row represents a member of staff and has a select dropdown with 3 options. Each of these selects has the same class `staff` The three option are Add, Edit and Delete

When the page loads a variable is loaded that gives a count to the current number of available staff training places.. Using PHP if that count is 0 I hide the Add option from the selects.

What I'm trying to now is manipulate the rows when the count is reached.

eg: if the count is already 0 the Add option is hidden, but if the count is 3 then they can apply the Add option to 3 members of staff, but not to any more.

When the staff option is selected I can call and external page are retrieved the current count.

```
$(".sfaff").on("click", function() {
    var staffCheck = (this.options[this.selectedIndex].text.length)

     //use AJAX to get currentCount
});
```

How do I then remove the Add option from the select in the rows below `this` ?

Comment: There is a [`remove(index)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove) function on `select` elements. Otherwise jQuery has its own [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function. If you show us your HTML, it would make it easier to tell you exactly how. Would also be nice to see what you've tried...

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The issue isn't actually removing or hiding the entry, its how to target specific entries and then remove from them

Comment: Okay. Still need the HTML in order to help with that.

Comment: thanks I'll try and upload the HTML tomorrow. I think the easiest thing will be if I can hide/remove the option from `this` entry.